# Fluent NHibernate Mapping for DDD Model

Tags: .net, fluent-nhibernate, domain-driven-design, mapping

I have been trying to look for solutions to the problem that I am currently having with mapping my DDD model using Fluent NHibernate. If someone can just put me in the right direction that would be appreciated.

Basically I have this class that I would like to map:

```
public class A : EntityObject
{
    //assuming some other attributes have been mapped properly

    public virtual Location MyLocation { get; private set; }
}

public class Location : EntityObject
{
    public virtual string Name { get; private set; }
}

public Class AMap : ClassMap<A>
{
    //????  How to map the Location
}
```

From database pov, there is no direct relationship from Table "A" to Table "Location". Table "A" has to go through Table "B" and Table "C" using join before having access to the LocationId column which can then me mapped to the Location table.

What's the best way in mapping the Location object in Fluent NHibernate? If there is anything that is unclear, please let me know.

Any help would be appreciated?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't understand your point about `table A` joining to `table Location` via `table b` and `table c`.  Are you saying that you already have a legacy DB structure that you have to work with?  From a DDD point of view, it may be better to think of Location as a Value Object (and maybe a component from a NH point of view), rather than an entity.

Comment: Hi, Sorry if I didn't explain the issue clear enough. Yes, I do have a legacy db to deal with. Basically, we have a location table in db that acts as a lookup table. and the locationId is stored in Table C. But we want to model everything into Class A. But due to the design of the db, we have to join it to Table B, then Table C before I can get the LocationId. My knowledge on DDD is not very strong yet. If you can elaborate more, that would be great.

Comment: @UpTheCreek Would you take a look at this question again but [re-phrased with a more detailed example](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5931917/56145) please?

Answer (score 0):

Well not having that much info about your domain i think like UpTheCreek - that you may model Location as a ValueObject that extends Class A.

I see two options. 1, the class A has a indirect relationship to Location through a LocationRepository where you can GetLocationByA(A a)

2, you model Location as a Valueobject that is part of class A's aggregate and is loaded through A's repository. Depending on you domain model and the relationship between Location and A, Location is loaded on the fly or during constructor of A. Sorry for the formatting below...

```
public class AMap : ClassMap<A>
{
    public AMap()
    {
Component(x => x.MyLocation, m =>
                          {
                              m.Map(x => x.Name, "Name");
                          });
    }
}
```